# What should I consider if I want to lend my camping van to friends?

Tags: car-rentals, automobiles, road-trips, campers

I agreed with some friends that they can borrow my camping van for a short roadtrip in Europe. I'm currently thinking about what should be done before the trip, and here's the list that I came up with. Am I missing something? Is there something superfluous on the list?

- Agree on the exact conditions (dates, duration, my compensation, etc.)
- Make sure that car insurance covers third-party drivers
- Make sure that all necessary papers (insurance card and car registration) are in the car
- An informal document signed by me that states that they are allowed to drive my car

Comment: Agree on how they hand back the van, cleaned or paying for getting it cleaned, specially important if a young group or a stag/hen party group.

Comment: We might see things differently, but if i am lending my van to a "friend", i would not make such rules. either you trust the "friend" and lend it, or not trust the friend and not lend it.. easier this way..

Comment: Well, in my opinion these aren't really rules, but more things that need to be done to allow for a hassle free roadtrip. One could argue that the first one is a rule, but it's more like that I know when I get my van back :)

Comment: @HeidelBerGensis I think we do see this separately, but to me there is no harm done in saying ‘and remember to clean it before I get it back ;)’

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not abut travel.

Comment: @RoflcoptrException different kind of friends, for my friends, if i lend them anything, i never expect it back.. they might ruin it just to laugh about it :/

Comment: Are you serious? Even when talking about expensive stuff like cars?

Comment: I do think this is travel-related, especially when being on the other end (i.e. the friends) and voting to leave open.

Comment: This is definitely travel related, because depending on the country the van is registered in I think you might require official documents stating that someone else than the owner is allowed to drive it over the border,

Comment: Clearly label and explain all tanks and their inlets. An acquaintance of mine once got his water tank filled with diesel.

Comment: My antennae extend slightly when I see the 'compensation' clause. There are probably legal restrictions on renting a car which could invalidate the insurance. 99 times out of 100 nothing will happen, but what if they accidentally maim someone and the insurance is invalid? You may have to pay up and try to recover the money from them, since you've clearly given them permission to drive the vehicle.

Comment: Your "compensation"? Does that mean that you are _renting_ your camper van to your "friends"? If so, you are surely breaking the law.

Answer (score 6):

Have your friends got European breakdown cover? Hopefully they won't need it! It may be prudent to go to your favourite mechanic beforehand for a quick check-up, as friends of mine spent 10 hours on the side of the road after their van broke down, and all they needed was a new fuel filter which cost a few euros.

Have you showed them around your van - all the nooks and crannies, how to do **xy** and **z** that maybe comes easily to you, but they might not know.. Shown them the particular way you change your oil, add water to the radiator and where your spare tyre is?

If you have any, you could give them those light reflectors that go on the headlamps. There's also a checklist here from the AA: http://www.theaa.com/motoring_advice/touring_tips/compulsory_equipment.pdf Of course the majority of these things are up to them to provide but at least you will have thought of everything from your side and reminded them of things they might still need to organise.

Additional information - An online list of advice for first time trip in a Camper around Europe gives some important information here that you may need to pass on to the driver and any passengers: http://www.campervanlife.com/locations/europe/1st-timer-tips

> Road laws vary between each country, and some require you to carry
>   equipment you might not already have.  Under French law, vehicles must
>   carry one reflective jacket for the driver, although many French
>   families store one for each passenger in case there is a breakdown and
>   they have to wait beside the car.
>
> If you breakdown, or are stopped by the police, put the jacket on, or else you may find yourself with a fine
>       In Spain you require a jacket for each person.
>       In France, Spain and Germany you are required to carry a red warning triangle.  Should you breakdown the triangle must be erected
>   30 meters behind the car.
>       In Spain you require 2 red warning triangles per car.
>       In Spain you are also required to carry a set of spare lamps/bulbs for your car and the tools to change them
>
> Here's a quick kit list:
>
> Greece
>       - First aid kit
>       - Fire extinguisher
>       - Warning triangle
>
> Italy
>       - Warning triangle
>       - Reflective jacket
>
> France
>       - Warning triangle
>       - Reflective jacket
>       - Headlamp adjustment
>
> Spain
>       - Warning triangle x 2
>       - Spare bulbs
>       - Headlamp adjustment
>       - Reflective jacket